# Is there some way to listen for changes under a tree URI on SAF?

Tags: android, storage, storage-access-framework

My use-case is pretty simple:

1. List files under a selected folder.
2. Listen for any changes over this folder (deletion, renaming, creation, etc.). So, for instance, even if the user deletes a child file `A` using a third-party app (e.g the OS file manager) my app will be able to catch the event and delete the file reference, to avoid ghost files in my recycler view.

To list the files under a selected folder, which is a simple tree URI that my app gains access through `openDocumentTree`, I'm already using SAF, I can use the tree URI to delete, rename, move child documents, etc. so permission is not a problem here.

But I am not able to find any resource pointing to some way to do the "listening" part. I've already:

- Read the Google storage documentation, but they cover every edge-case but not this one https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data.
- I tried to see an example of it on the [android/storage-samples](https://github.com/android/storage-samples) repository but even there they are just reloading the entire directory when the user renames a folder, and it is not handling when the user does the alter by a third-party app, [android/storage-samples/blob/22784d8cbf1d990958ae554ec61afea1a9da93c1](https://github.com/android/storage-samples/blob/22784d8cbf1d990958ae554ec61afea1a9da93c1/ActionOpenDocumentTree/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/ktfiles/DirectoryFragment.kt#L133).
- https://github.com/K1rakishou/Fuck-Storage-Access-Framework library, no mention to any kind of listenable APIs.
- https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage library, no mention to any kind of listenable APIs.
- https://github.com/google/modernstorage, same...
- I even asked ChatGPT but he brings me a solution that doesn't works, the `ContentResolver.registerContentObserver`, which is exactly the approach of some unanswered SO questions (see below).

I found and tried some SO questions about it (a bit 'older' ~ 3 years), which also doesn't have answers yet:

- [Storage Access Framework: Register Content Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796380/storage-access-framework-register-content-observer).
- [Register content observer on external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180057/register-content-observer-on-external-storage).

My question is, do we have access to something that allow us to listen for changes over a folder that we've permission over?

I'm just about to give-up this shit and add `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and use the [FileObserver API](https://gist.github.com/gitanuj/888ef7592be1d3f617f6), and if it does not work either I think I'll just start brute-forcing the user storage searching for changes foff [image].

Comment: "But I am not able to find any resource pointing to some way to do the "listening" part" -- I am not aware that there is one. Bear in mind that the Storage Access Framework is an abstraction around storage, and not all types of storage support what you are describing, particularly cloud storage. Note that your proposed use of `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` means that you might not be allowed to distribute your app on the Play Store or elsewhere. You might need to reconsider your use case and see if you can come up with a fresh approach that does not require what you are seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commonsware said, that's not possible. I think the best I can do is just handle when the user try some action in an file that no longer exists by showing a warn then also deleting the file reference from my app.

- How to check if a tree URI exists [SAF - method checking folder Uri existence yields always true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181316/saf-method-checking-folder-uri-existence-yields-always-true).